# The Perfect Polynomial

Tags: code-golf, math, polynomials

The coefficients of a perfect square polynomial can be calculated by the formula \$(ax)^2 + 2abx + b^2\$, where both a and b are integers. The objective of this challenge is to create a program that not only can find if an input trinomial is a perfect square, but also find its square root binomial. The input trinomial will be written in this format:

```
1 2 1
```

which symbolizes the perfect square number \$x^2 + 2x+ 1\$, since all 3 input numbers represent coefficients of the trinomial. The outputs must be readable and understandable.
To count as a perfect square in this challenge, a trinomial must have \$a\$ and \$b\$ as real integer numbers. No fractions, decimals, irrational numbers or imaginary/complex numbers allowed in the final binomial. Make a program that accomplishes this, and since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: How flexible is the output? Can we for example output `true` as `1` and then `1 1` on a separate line? (That sort of flexibility is usually allowed). Also, what type of numbers will be input: only integers? Real? Complex? (Only integers is probably better, to avoid floating-point issues)

Comment: What can we do for output where it's not a perfect square? Some more test cases would be good.

Comment: Related to Luis Mendo's question on number types, what if the input is `2 4 2`? Its square root is \$ \sqrt 2 x + \sqrt 2 \$. Does it count as a perfect square?

Comment: Also, what about inputs like \$x^2+1\$? Does that count as the perfect square of \$x+i\$ where \$i\$ is the imaginary unit?

Comment: Can we take a representation of a polynomial in some variable, say `x`, or a function that applies the polynomial to its argument?

Comment: I'd say a perfect square must have a and b be both integers, rather than irrational numbers or fractions. Imaginary solutions are discarded since I said that a and b must be real. You can represent x in the argument if you want.

Comment: OP, I’m flattered that you accepted my answer, but it’s only been two hours, so I think you should wait for more answers. Anyways, Code Golf often has questions without an accepted answer

Comment: @NipDip Thanks for the clarifications. Please edit them into the question.

Comment: @NipDip With requiring that the output be integers, the accepted solution doesn't meet that.

Comment: Please put in more test cases, ideally covering all corner cases that programs might encounter. These might include various coefficients being negative or zero. In particular, can the input have zero quadratic term or even just be a constant? Can it even be all zero?

Comment: I downvoted because of [too restrictive output format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/36398) and because the [challenge text does not match the clarifications in the comments](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8112/36398). Let me know if you solve that so I can remove my downvote

Comment: Ok, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 42 bytes

**I would delete this, but I can't because it's been accepted.**

```javascript
(a,b,c)=>[A=Math.sqrt(a),b/A/2,b*b==c*a*4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bck7DoQgFAXQflYC5KqB2EzxJnEBrsBYPPAzGiMzQtw@2hptz5l55@C26Rez1Xd9GigJhoWT9Gkqqjl@8/DfomAJW1SFgVWWyClWZZucX4Nf@nzxoxiEhoGW8nVVgxLmpm/oM545Oz0d)

Can be called as `f(a,b,c)`. Output is in the form `[<factor of x>, <constant>, True/False]` (if it's False, then the first 2 values are meaningless).